# Getting memory permission details in Linux

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, mprotect

I am using mmap for allocation memory and mark some pages as PROT_READ and few as PROT_NONE using mprotect. my implementation has logic based on the memory permission. Currently I have the memory location info, how do I get its current protection state? (PROT_READ/PROT_NONE)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if there's a syscall to retrieve this information.
Absolute worst case you could parse `/proc/<pid>/maps`.

Comment: Parsing `/proc/$pid/maps` or `/proc/self/maps` from inside the application, and also `/proc/$pid/smaps` or `/proc/$pid/smaps` is the Linux way to get that information (it is not the *worst case*, it is the *good way* on Linux, and there are no other ways).